# How to map two tables to each other in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, model-view-controller

I'm trying to set up a lookup between two tables in my MVC project, where nHibernate is massively in use. I've got both tables mapped, and that works well as long as I treat them as separate entities. But now I'm in need, farther down the road, of the ability while loading table1 to pull data from table2, in a one-to-one mapping.

**Lead.cs**

```
using System;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace SMSService.Models
{
    //Table One
    public class Leads
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual string TaskName { get; set; }

        //The second table
        public virtual Workflow Workflow { get; set; }
    }

    public class LeadsClassMap : ClassMap<Leads>
    {
        public LeadsClassMap()
        {
            Table("Leads");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
            Map(x => x.FirstName);
            Map(x => x.LastName);
            Map(x => x.TaskName);

            //My attempt to join the tables
            HasOne(x => x.Workflow).Column("LeadId");
        }
    }
}
```

**Workflow.cs**

```
using System;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace SMSService.Models
{
    //Table Two
    public class Workflow
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int LeadId { get; set; }
        public virtual bool PreviouslySubmitted { get; set; }
        public virtual Guid SubmittedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public virtual int WorkflowStep { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkflowClassMap : ClassMap<Workflow>
    {
        public WorkflowClassMap()
        {
            Table("Workflow");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
            Map(x => x.LeadId);
            Map(x => x.PreviouslySubmitted);
            Map(x => x.SubmittedBy);
            Map(x => x.Modified);
            Map(x => x.WorkflowStep);
        }
    }
}
```

My goal then, in using this would be that I could have a method that calls Leads, and also Workflows, so that I could do something like:

```
foreach (var lead in Leads) {
    var prevSubmitted = lead.Workflow.PreviouslySubmitted;
}
```

The first problem I encounter, however, is that I get ".Column" red-Flagged in the code with the error of "Cannot resolve symbol 'Column'". So I'm not sure if my syntax is utterly wrong, or I'm missing something key somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be a true one to one relationship.  True one to one relationships share the same primary key which is not the case here.

This seems to be a many to one instead which should be mapped like the below.  I will also say that generally I do not map just id columns.  If this is a foreign key in the database it should be tied to the actual nhibernate entity and not just an id.  This becomes invaluable when doing queries in nhibernate.  I've changed LeadId below in the Workflow class to match this.

```
public class Leads
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string TaskName { get; set; }

    //The second table
    public virtual IList<Workflow> Workflows { get; set; }
}

public class LeadsClassMap : ClassMap<Leads>
{
    public LeadsClassMap()
    {
        Table("Leads");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        Map(x => x.TaskName);

        //My attempt to join the tables
        HasMany(x => x.Workflows)
            .KeyColumn("LeadId")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class Workflow
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Leads Lead { get; set; }
    public virtual bool PreviouslySubmitted { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid SubmittedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public virtual int WorkflowStep { get; set; }
}

public class WorkflowClassMap : ClassMap<Workflow>
{
    public WorkflowClassMap()
    {
        Table("Workflow");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        References(x => x.Lead, "LeadId");
        Map(x => x.PreviouslySubmitted);
        Map(x => x.SubmittedBy);
        Map(x => x.Modified);
        Map(x => x.WorkflowStep);
    }
}
```

Comment: It actually is 1:1, just not enforced on a constraint. For every record in Lead, there will always be, and can only be, 1 record in Workflow. The reason the Workflow has a "LeadId" is primarily because I was hoping to prevent any errors when a record might get deleted from one table, but not from the other (which in a dev environment, happens a lot).

Comment: I still disagree with you that this is a 1-1.  Take a look at http://www.jagregory.com/writings/i-think-you-mean-a-many-to-one-sir/ .  In any event you can still change the above mapping to be `References(x => x.WorkFlow, "LeadId")` and also change the collection `public virtual IList<Workflow> Workflows { get; set; }` to `public virtual Workflow Workflow { get; set; }` to achieve what you want.  If there is nothing preventing you from have multiple records in Workflow with the same LeadId I would expect to encounter problems eventually.

Answer (score 0):

One to one mapping won't work in this case as they are not using the same Id, so one way to fix is,

```
References(x => x.Workflow).Column("LeadId");
```